# jQuery CSS themeroller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, button, themeroller

I want to take an icon from the jQuery Themeroller and implement it as a button. Then, when I click the icon, it toggles between one color and another color. This is in Ruby on Rails. How should I do this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI buttons or plain ones?

Comment: I want to use jQuery icons as the button.

Comment: That isn't what I asked.  jQuery UI has specific support for themed buttons.  Are you using it?

Comment: Yeah, they have themed buttons but I don't believe any of them have an arrow in them, which is what I want, since these buttons are for up and down voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is front-end code, so it's pretty much all JS/jQuery, what you're trying to accomplish has nothing to do with Rails.

The icons are separate classes, for example .jquery-ui-wrench.

One way to do it is:

```
<div id="some_button" class="jquery-ui-wrench"></div>
```

And then somewhere:

```
$('#some_button').click(function(){
  // Code to toggle button, probably 
  $('#some_button').removeClass('jquery-ui-wrench');
  $('#some_button').addClass('colored-version-of-icon');
});
```

**Including, as per comment**

Once you've downloaded your custom theme + jQuery UI from the site, extract the .js files into your `public/javascripts`, then the css stylesheet into `public/stylesheets`, and the images into `public/images`. Edit the css file and replace all occurances of `images` with `/images`. (This is to ensure it points to the images folder correctly)

Then simply include the stylesheet and javascript file in your layout, and you should be able to start using it.

Comment: Could you please add how to include the themeroller into your application.

Comment: This only goes one way though. How do you switch between the classes if there is more than one click?

Comment: Use a variable that tracks state, or look up the toggleClass method in jQuery